# Ruby post match returning Nil.. like its supposed too

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, while-loop

My while loop is busted somehow.. I get this error:

```
`block in scrape': undefined method `post_match' for nil
:NilClass   (NoMethodError)
```

Its returning nil like its supposed too after going through the string, and it populates the array like its supposed too, but the last time it hits the .post_match it fails because its a nil.. but its supposed to be a nil.. not sure what to do?? I WANT it to just populate the array and then exit the loop once parent_pic_first is nil.

```
parent_pic_first = /\"hiRes\":\"/.match(pic).post_match

   while parent_pic_first != nil

        parent_pic = URI.extract(parent_pic_first, ['http'])

        pic_list = []

        pic_list.push(parent_pic[0])

        parent_pic_first = /\"hiRes\":\"/.match(parent_pic_first).post_match

        end
```

Comment: Mind giving the exact error? And as a quick check, what happens when you replace `!= nil` with `parent_pic_first.nil?`

Comment: update the post with the error.. but parent_pic_first.nil? isn't really what I want.. because if its nil and I used parent_pic_first.nil? it would be true.. and I want it to be false.. basically !.nil? if there is such a thing?

Comment: Yes, actually but it's `!parent_pic_first.nil?` IIRC. it's been a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't the fact that `parent_pic_first` is `nil`, the problem is that `/\"hiRes\":\"/.match(parent_pic_first)` is `nil`. You're attempting to call a method `post_match` on a `nil` value. `nil.post_match` is quite obviously not going to work.

You need to add in some checks to prevent calling `post_match` on a `nil`, so something like this:

```
parent_pic_first = /\"hiRes\":\"/.match(pic).post_match

while parent_pic_first != nil
  parent_pic = URI.extract(parent_pic_first, ['http'])
  pic_list = []
  pic_list.push(parent_pic[0])
  regex_return = /\"hiRes\":\"/.match(parent_pic_first)
  if regex_return.nil?
    break
  else      
    parent_pic_first = regex_return.post_match
  end
end
```